# Dynamically ending ODE integration in SciPy

Tags: python, ode, scipy, grid

I have a light ray moving through space-time, i.e. a curve in $\mathbb{R}^4$, parametrized by some variable λ. The exact trajectory, i.e. the coordinate functions $x^μ(λ)$ of the curve are given by some ODE $\frac{dx^μ}{dλ} = f(λ)$.

Now, I've got two requirements for my code to satisfy:

1. The results $x^μ(λ)$ must be given on a regular grid, i.e. the step size dλ must be the same everywhere.
2. I don't know the interval λ runs over beforehand, i.e. integration must end dynamically as soon as a certain condition $g(λ, x^μ(λ))$ is met (basically I'm testing whether the coordinates $x^μ(λ)$ are outside of some coordinate interval where I don't know the space-time's properties anymore).

Requirement 2 obviously excludes `scipy.odeint()`. This leaves me with the `scipy.ode` class which allows me to pass the break condition to the integrator via a `solout` callback if I choose the `dopri5` or the `dop853` algorithm.

It's a bit more complicated, though: Since these (and all other) integrators dynamically adjust their internal step size (which is kind of the point of not doing the integration manually) I cannot simply store the values being passed to the callback if I want to fulfill requirement 1. (Update: In fact, it doesn't make sense to do so, anyway. See my remark (*) below.) Instead, I still need to loop over λ and call the `scipy.ode.integrate()` method for each step $λ + dλ$. This, however, means that I must somehow stop the loop:

```
from scipy.integrate import ode

def deriv(λ, x, params):
    # …
    return dx_dλ

end_reached = False

def solout(λ, x):
    if g(λ, x):
        # Stop integration
        # Returning -1 will NOT make solver.successful() return False, so
        # we need to inform the integration loop (see below) separately.
        nonlocal end_reached
        end_reached = True
        return -1

    # Everything's ok. Move on.
    return 0

λ0 = 0
x0 = …
params = …
dλ = 0.1

solver = ode(deriv)
solver.set_integrator('dopri5', nsteps=500)
solver.set_solout(solout)
solver.set_initial_value(x0, λ0)
solver.set_f_params(params)

λ = [λ0]
x = [x0]

while True:
    solver.integrate(solver.t + dλ)

    if not solver.successful() or end_reached:
        break

    λ.append(solver.t)
    x.append(solver.y)
```

All in all, this is rather ugly. Not only is the logic basically all over the place (for instance I cannot test the condition in the loop where it would belong). But due to the `solout` callback (I suppose) it's also at least one order of magnitude slower than without one. **Update**: In fact, even without the callback, the `dopri5` integrator is orders of magnitude slower than `vode` (at least for another ODE where I wanted to use this approach).

Am I missing something or is this really the only way to meet the above requirements? I also tried raising an exception in `deriv()` (and subsequently catching it in the loop) in order to stop the integrator. While this works for all integrators, it will still lead to a bunch of errors being printed to stdout.

(*) As far as I understand, the values passed to `deriv()` are not meant to be a reliable approximation but only the final value returned by the solver is. For instance, the solver might do overshooting to choose a sensible step size in view of (rapidly) changing slopes and to thereby arrive at a best estimate.

Comment: I don't understand.  Isn't requirement 2 the one that involves a "break condition"?

Comment: Sorry, it's been a long day. I edited my post accordingly.

Comment: Why must your code satisfy requirement 1? Does it matter if condition $g$ is met in the middle of a time step, and if so, how does that affect requirement 1?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. I want the *output* to be on a regular grid because I need to process it later and I need a simple parameter which allows me to change the sampling rate / resolution in a predictable way.

Comment: $g$ is a hard break condition, meaning that integration must stop immediately as soon as it is met. The reason is that my equations become invalid for `g = true` resulting in invalid data and, even worse, in [excess work](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2009-June/021640.html) being done by the integrator. In case $g$ is met in the middle of a time step, integration should simply stop without adding another data point to the results (which would obviously destroy the regularity of the grid).

Comment: Could you simplify the notation in the question? Is the \mu important? Also, if I'm understanding correctly, the ODE you wrote dx/dλ = f(λ) is the kind of ODE you can solve with quadrature. More or less x(t) = cumsum(arange(0,T,dλ))*dλ + x_0. Did you mean to write: dx/dλ = f(λ,x) ?

Comment: Scipy new releases already support event handling: [scipy.integrate.solve_ivp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The feature that you demand is called *event location* in Matlab ODE solvers pack, or *rootfinding* in [SUNDIALS solvers suite](http://computation.llnl.gov/casc/sundials/main.html) terminology. Essentially this feature allows to stop integration exactly at the point where some vector function of free and dependent variables has a root. Namely, for system
$$
\frac{d\boldsymbol y}{dt} = f(t, \boldsymbol y),
    \quad \boldsymbol y \in \mathbb R^n,
$$
an ODE solver with the ability to do event location will be able to find when some function $ g(t, \boldsymbol y)$ crosses zero—and this process of zero-crossing is called an *event*.

Unfortunately, `scipy.integrate` lacks good ODE solver with the support of event location. You can use `solout` feature of `dopri5` solver, but you will overshoot in this case, because `solout` is called only after step is done. In contrast, when ODE solver is able to do event location, it will work hard on finding the exact location of the root of $g(t, \boldsymbol y)$, so that the integration will be stopped much more precisely.

I also need this feature for my computations. I use the following package https://github.com/bmcage/odes. This package is quite difficult to compile, because it depends on BLAS, LAPACK and SUNDIALS. However, interface (API) is quite good, and it will work much better than using `solout` feature of `dopri5` from `scipy.integrate`.

Comment: It seems that https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html has improved the situation for `scipy.integrate`!

Answer (score 4):

The solution is
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html

From the documentation : ‘RK45’ or ‘RK23’ method for non-stiff problems and ‘Radau’ or ‘BDF’ for stiff problems

The documentation taken from scipy:

> scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(fun, t_span, y0, method='RK45', t_eval=None,
>   dense_output=False, events=None, vectorized=False, **options)[source]
>   Solve an initial value problem for a system of ODEs.
>
> **Parameters:**
>   . 
>   . 
>   . 
>   . 
>   .
>
> **events:** callable, or list of callables, optional Events to track. If None (default), no events will be tracked. Each event occurs at the
>   zeros of a continuous function of time and state. Each function must
>   have the signature event(t, y) and return a float. The solver will
>   find an accurate value of t at which event(t, y(t)) = 0 using a
>   root-finding algorithm. By default, all zeros will be found. The
>   solver looks for a sign change over each step, so if multiple zero
>   crossings occur within one step, events may be missed. Additionally
>   each event function might have the following attributes:
>
> terminal: bool, optional Whether to terminate integration if this
>   event occurs. Implicitly False if not assigned.
>
> direction: float, optional Direction of a zero crossing. If direction
>   is positive, event will only trigger when going from negative to
>   positive, and vice versa if direction is negative. If 0, then either
>   direction will trigger event. Implicitly 0 if not assigned.
>
> You can assign attributes like event.terminal = True to any function
>   in Python.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up raising an exception in the `deriv()` function (and catching it in the loop) because it turned out to be the only reliable way to end integration in every single case and for every ODE.

(While I considered this option already in my original question, it seems there is no other way. If anybody presents a better option I will gladly mark her/his answer as accepted. **Update:** I accepted Dmitry's answer.)

Answer (score 2):

A simpler answer, IMHO, is to solve your system using [PyDSTool](http://pydstool.sf.net). It has built-in support for [accurate event finding](http://www.ni.gsu.edu/~rclewley/PyDSTool/Events.html). In fact, it's easier to set up and more efficient (including faster) than Matlab's approach if you use the C-based solvers. I am the author of this package.

A tutorial using events is given [here](http://www.ni.gsu.edu/~rclewley/PyDSTool/Tutorial/Tutorial_VdP.html).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the solve_ivp package went through an update, but I just found a workaround that gives it the capability to detect events not at the root of the function.  In the "limit" function, a limiting case can be described that depends on the value of the integrated function.

However, the solver expects the return to be a list the first time this is evaluated, and a numpy array every time after that. Typically, the input to the function is passed directly back to solve_ivp, and this is not a problem.  However, if a custom condition is desired, that has to be accounted for.  I did it with a global variable, as shown below.  If the value "0" is returned from the function "limit", the solver will stop immediately.

```
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

 # Define derivative function 
 def f(t, y, c):
     dydt = (0.5*t) 
     return dydt

 # stop integration when y-1 = 0 (arbitrary condition)
 def limit(t,y):
     global flag
     if flag == 1:
         test = np.array(y)-np.array(1)
         test = np.ndarray.tolist(test)
         flag = 0
     else:
         test = np.array(y) - np.array(1)
     return test

 # Define terminal condition and type-change flag
 limit.terminal = True                                                                                                                                                                                   
 global flag
 flag = 1

 # Define time spans, initial values, and constants
 tspan = np.linspace(0.5, 3, 1000)
 yinit = [-1]
 c = []

 # Solve differential equation
 sol = solve_ivp(lambda t, y: f(t, y, c),[tspan[0], tspan[-1]], yinit, t_eval=tspan,events=limit)

 t = sol.t
 y = np.transpose(sol.y)
 plt.plot(t,y)
 plt.show()
```